# Angular can't retrive simple Integer as a backend reposne

Tags: javascript, angularjs, response, angular-resource

From the backend I'm getting simple integer:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('WORKER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/countFiles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Integer> countFiles(HttpServletRequest request){
    return fileService.countFiles(request);
}
```

**UPDATE - Service site:**

```
  public ResponseEntity<Integer> countFiles(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Principal name = request.getUserPrincipal();
        if (name.getName() == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
        }
        User userByLogin = userRepository.findUserByLogin(name.getName());
        fileDao.countByUser(userByLogin);
        return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(fileDao.countByUser(userByLogin), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

At frontend site created simple method:

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp').factory('FileService', function ($resource) {
    var service = $resource('api/file', {
        id: '@id'
    }, {
        saveFile: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/file',
            headers: {'content-Type': undefined}
        },
        countFiles: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/file/countFiles',
            responseType: 'text'
        }
    });
    return service;
});
```

**Angular controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('sbAdminApp');
app.controller('GoogleMapCtrl', function ($scope, $log, uiUploader, FileService, $http) {
    $scope.name = "Hello";
    console.log('count', FileService.countFiles());
});
```

But the output looks like:
[image]

So there is no my clount at all..It should be 27.

**================UPDATE=====================**

```
  var val;
    FileService.countFiles().$promise.then(function(response) {
        console.log('respone', response.data);
        val = response.value();
    });
    console.log('val', val)
```

Abouve code return both for var and when I print `undefinded`

Comment: share code regarding how you are using your service..

Comment: How are you calling your angular service method?

Comment: sorry, I meant to ask about angular controller (should have mentioned factory and not service)

Comment: @tanmay  - please have a look at latest update

Comment: it should be like this `FileService.countFiles().$promise.then(function(response) { $scope.val = response.data; });`

Comment: @Hadi Jeddizahed please have a look at post update

Comment: @bielas put your console.log inside promise handler function

Comment: @tanmay, there is... `var val;
    FileService.countFiles().$promise.then(function(response) {
        console.log('respone', response.data);
        val = response.value();
    });
    console.log('val', val)`

Comment: try this `FileService.countFiles().$promise.then(function(response) { $scope.val = response.value; });`

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed undefined..

Comment: please see this https://ibb.co/mEFdwQ

Comment: I dont have that...- http://imgur.com/EOmFdbE

Comment: Apparently you don't have correct response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141705/discussion-between-bielas-and-hadi-jeddizahed).

Answer (score 0):

Your Service/Factory method 'countFiles' returns a promise. So you have to "wait" for the promise to be resolved.

```
FileService.countFiles().$promise.then(function(response) {
    $scope.val = response.value();
}
```

Comment: Added:
`var val;
    FileService.countFiles().$promise.then(function(response) {
        $scope.val = response;
    });
    console.log('val', val)`
and got val is undefinded. If I put the response.value() the result it: `response.value is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log('val', val)` would get executed first if written outside since we wait for the promise to get resolved. So, it should be,

```
var val;
FileService.countFiles().$promise.then(function(response) {
    console.log('respone', response.data);
    //val = response.value;
    //console.log('val', val); 
});
```

Comment: I don't think so. It's not a first example when I have that kind of problem. It returns fine number. Now when I put that number from API into some object and return it, everythink will work perfectly fine...

Comment: @bielas look at the image you've sent above. it shows `response undefined` right above the error which is first `console.log`

Comment: Changed into the object from backend:
`@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('WORKER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/countFiles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<FileModel> countFiles(HttpServletRequest request){
        return fileService.countFiles(request);
    }` 
and you see:
`var val =  FileService.countFiles();
    console.log('val', val)` -> http://imgur.com/MbRWNtW
but I want to return just Integer, not whole object from backend

Comment: @bielas I would suggest to keep it this way. just assign `.count` to your variable and good to go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141704/discussion-between-bielas-and-tanmay).